# Hadoop API: OutputFormat for Reducer

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

I am totally confused with hadoop API. (guess its changing all the time)

If i am not wrong, `JobConf` was `deprecated` and we were supposed to use `Job` and `Configuration` classes instead to run a map reduce job from java. it seems though that in recently released `hadoop 1.0.0` `JobConf` is not longer deprecated!

So i am using Job and configuration classes to run a map reduce job. Now, i need to put reducers output files in a folder structure based on certain values that are part of my map output. I went through several articles and found that one can achieve that with a `OutputFormat` Class but we have this class in two packages:

```
org.apache.hadoop.mapred and 
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce
```

In our `job` object we can set a output format class as:

```
job.setOutputFormatClass(SomeOutputFormat.class);
```

Now if `SomeOutputFormat` `extends` say `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat` , we get one method named `getRecordWriter();` this does not help in any way to override the output path.

There is another way by using `jobConf` but that again does not seem to work in terms of setting `mappers, reducers, partitions, sorting and grouping` classes.

Is there something very obvious that i am missing? I want to write my reduce output file inside a folder which is based on a value. for exmaple, `SomeOutputPrefix/Value1/Value2/realReduceFileName`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to implement

1. your own output format class and
2. your own RecordWriter which will be writing different values to different places

So your SomeOutputWriter will return `new SomeRecordWriter("SomeOutputPrefix")` in its `getRecordWriter()` method, and `SomeRecordWriter` will write different values to different folders.

Comment: thanks DNNX. was on these lines but wanted to see if there were any other easier ways of doing it. seems this is the way to do it. Had to tweak my partioning logic a bit to work properly with record writer. and it worked.